# How to fix git path after MacOS Sierra update?

Tags: macos, git

I have just upgraded from OS X 10.11 "El Capitan" to 10.12 "Sierra", and when I open intellijIdea, I get the following error:

> Can't start Git: /usr/bin/git Probably the path to Git executable is not valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My problem solved after running xcode installation with following code from terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Great! I probably shouldn't have posted my answer, then. (:

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Xcode installed? Try `xcode-select -p` to print where the system thinks it is, and `xcode-select -s /path/to/Xcode.app` to tell the system where it is. (Git is stored inside Xcode.)

Answer (score -1):

In recent MacOS updates the git path is :

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.16.2/bin/git
```

Instead of 2.16.2 Choose your version

Comment: You have shared the path for Git installed via Homebrew. OP has not mentioned if he has installed Git via Homebrew or not.